# Free word processing software that supports importing multiple images

Tags: windows, gratis, images, word-processor

There's an old stack exchange thread about google docs where someone figured out how to import multiple images- the solution they found no longer works. Now google drive says "you can only drag and drop one image a time"

Wordpad that comes free with windows 10 does not support importing multiple images at once

I want to put all of my images in one document that I can type on and print. I don't like selecting images from the folder and right clicking print because there are sizing issues that don't happen for just importing images into say a word doc or rtf file

What's my best bet? Ideally, I'd be able to open this document on various different computers through google drive or dropbox

I use a windows 10 laptop and am looking for a free solution

Answer (score 2):

**LibreOffice** suite's Writer can import several images by just dropping them from Windows Explorer. (I have not installed OpenOffice on this computer, but it probably will work similarly) But dropping them inside the application is just a part of the process. In this case all the photos will be stacked one on top of each other and you need to manually arrange them.

Probably you need to review your real priority. I still do not understand your real need. Using a word processor to carry and print images is, in my opinion, a bad idea. A word processor is a bad idea because the new pages are inserted if they need more space for new rows of text. I understand that you need to type something? on the top of them... Is this just a small text, like a date, or is this a design?

So probably a better option is to use Draw, which is another LibreOffice application for drawing, and inserting images. Well inclusive Impress, that is LibreOffice suite's PowerPoint equivalent, in which you can drag a photo to the miniature viewer.

> I don't like selecting images from the folder and right-clicking Print because there are sizing issues.

Are this "sizing issues" your real limitation? There are image viewers that can print resizing the images or leaving a specific margin. There are some that can print for example 2,3,4 or whatever number of images per page. Probably these limitations are easily solved changing the configuration of an application.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is not a word-processing application, but the scanner tool of my choice: [NAPS2](https://www.naps2.com/) (Not Another PDF Scanner 2).

This tool will allow you to drag-and-drop multiple images and PDFs (or directly from the scanner), if the image/PDF has multiple pages, it will import each of the pages in.

At this point you will have the choice of: editing the pages, exporting to a PDF (either all the pages or selectively) or saving individual images, and of course it will allow you to print.

I really like this one, it has become part of my 'standard installs'